# Python functools.reduce, how to reduce a list a return a new one

Tags: python, lambda, reduce, fold

Answering a question I notice that I don't know how to return a list after doing append inside a reduce, for example

```
import functools

futures = [1,2,3]
records = functools.reduce((lambda res, future: res if (res.append(str(future))  == None) else res), futures, [])
```

I want the list `['1', '2', '3']`, it is just a minimal example, because I want to do more than map values.

Is there a another way that this horrible if that I put inside the lambda?

Comment: How about `lambda res, future: res+[str(future)]`?

Comment: @Rawing I think thtat is! why a comment and not an answer? If you put it as answer I will accept gladly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to *mutate* the result list in your lambda; `reduce` takes the *return value* of the function as the result. So your lambda can be as simple as

```
lambda res, future: res+[str(future)]
```